# Workplace conficts - try to resolve or resign?

Tags: work-environment, politics, stress

I have been facing few critical issues at my workplace just within three months of joining. The work environment has been so stressful and negative in both 
personal and professional aspects. I've described few scenarios below, I wanted to get some advice on should I stay and deal/try to solve the office politics and better resign immediately and search for another job.

Few scenarios
1) There was a task assigned with a deadline of a week. A peer, person A, quietly finishes the task without notifying me at all. Next day he boasts that he finished the task all by himself and projected that I could not finish it in time. I still had a week to finish that task though. I was resolving few support tickets at that time. The managers feel that behavior is appropriate. Work allocations are random, any one comes to the desk and assigns works. My direct manager says these things can happen in a dynamic environment and fast-paced work place. I feel this is chaotic not dynamic.

2) When I ask my manager why there is no proper task allocations to the team, in spite of having a project management and task plan template, he gets furious and removed me in next development cycle.

3) I and other colleague have been working on a new feature. In a meeting with business users, person A claims the he is doing that work, and there is no sign of acknowledgement for us. The managers feel this is fine and there is nothing wrong in it. How can one person claim credit for the work done by other team members and it is shocking to know that managers do not see this as a problem.

4) When discussed with HR, she is totally clueless and trying to be neutral without actually taking any kind of initiative to resolve the issues.

5) In one of the team meetings, I was asked my opinion on a topic. I was told to "please shut up" even before I finished my words.

6) I took a day off stating I was too stressed out. My manager updated my HR that I've seen a medical doctor who certified that I had some stress induced disorder and that I needed some accommodations at work. I clarified to HR that this is totally rubbish.

Comment: Hi, Kris. Sorry to hear you're having a tough time at work. However, it would be behoove all of us involved if this post included a possible solution as open-ended questions for advice are [a little off-topic here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) :/. Just letting you know as part of the community QA review. Meanwhile, welcome to The Workplace Stack Exchange and thanks for your question!

Comment: Also, each situation could almost possibly be posted as a separate question similar to, "This is how I had handled it, how else could I have approached the situation?" Presented as they are now with the question as it is currently written, this is almost just [a laundry list of complaints](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2696/62982).

Comment: Either way, I had upvoted Joe Strazzere's comment for you to find a new job. If you're not happy, it's not worth it :). Though, be careful -- the grass is always greener on the other side, that is, until we find out that they had simply photoshopped it to make it look greener :/.

Comment: Sounds awfully toxic to me. Get out of there a.s.a.p.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just started, these are critical months that get you off on the right/wrong foot and so far you have been to HR twice, complained about a successful coworker and your manager. This doesn't look good. Neither does resigning.

It's up to you how you handle things, you can either buckle down and keep quiet and put in some solid work until you have earnt respect, or you can resign and learn from this. If you resign find another job first.

Realistically workplace respect is earnt, not given, you generally do not start going to HR in your first months before people actually start taking notice of you and valuing you. Because until they do, you don't really have any value in your peers eyes, and at the moment you quite possibly have negative value.

This can happen to new employees, and it can be lived down, personally I'd soldier through it because jobs are not that easy to come by over here. But I suggest you don't dig a deeper hole than you already have.

Answer (score 6):

You're the only one here who can decide whether to resolve these issues or resign. However, assuming you go down the "resolve" route, allow me to offer the following perspectives on the situation:

1) Communication is key here - and if you're not getting it by default from other team members, you need to make sure you're asking for it! Make sure you're working on the project steadily each day - if you're ignoring it for a few days with the plan of doing it later, then it's going to look to the other team members like you don't know where to start with it, and they may well take over. Before you pick a task up, ask around to see if others have started it, when you've completed a task, make sure others know!

2) It sounds to me like you inadvertendly insulted your manager here - asking why tasks aren't allocated properly to his team is similar to saying "why aren't you doing your job properly?" That's not going to go down well with anyone (especially when it's the new kid that's saying it.) Instead, ask what *your* priorities should be, and how *you* can avoid work conflicts with others.

3) Fact of life: Clients likely couldn't care less about what member of the team wrote what particular feature - they care that the work is being done (not by whom.) Your colleague probably didn't know who was working on this feature, but didn't care (and said he was working on it so the client at least thought something was being done about it!)

4) Rule of thumb - HR aren't there to deal with the new guy's complaints about the structure of their team, they're there to protect the company from lawsuits. It doesn't involve HR at all, so no wonder they were clueless.

5) There must be more to this. I've *never* seen a conversation go along the lines of this (outside of a comedy sketch):

- "Dave, do you think we should do `x`, or `y`?"
- "Good question, I'd actually be tempted to agree with John and go with.."
- "Actually, shut up Dave."

6) Most likely situation: **Your manager said this to cover for you, so you wouldn't get in trouble for taking time off for no reason. You then spat this back in his face by telling HR he was making it up.**

Comment: I cannot even imagine a conversation that would end in "Actually, shut up Gnasher". That said, your point #6 is very bad for the OP.

Comment: @berry120 -for #6, The reason for my stress is the mis-management at workplace.My manager covered that up saying I have a stress-related health disorder? How is he trying to cover for me. I hold 6 years work experience before and have not faced such issues elsewhere.

Comment: @kris He's covering for you because you took a day off without authorisation. Regardless as to the cause of stress, you can't just decide you've had a stressful week / few weeks and sign yourself off for a day because you think you're team is mismanaged. If you *actually* suffer from stress, go see a doctor who can sign you off and recommend some course of action. If you just felt like you needed a day to yourself because your manager annoyed you... well good luck getting that to fly with HR.

Comment: @berry120- Thanks, seems that you are totally misunderstood it. Please ignore.

Comment: @kris I may have misunderstood entirely. As said in the answer, I'm merely offering an alternate perspective on the situations that you presented that may help you view them from your co-workers' line of thinking. Personally, I find it unlikely that everything is exactly as you've presented it and everyone's out to get you - but if that really is 100% the case and you genuinely can't cope with being there, the answer is obvious (get a new job and then get out there ASAP.)

Answer (score 1):

To me, it looks like you are working on a different mindset than the rest of your team. Whether that is good or not, confrontation in your situation is the less likely to pay off.

If I were you I'd seek for other projects where this is not the "way to roll", if that's not possible, because the whole organisation works this way or because there are no other areas in need of your skills, then it is a good time to look for opportunities outside, however, you should not just dump it and go seek for another job, that is a terrible decision that can cost you months of unemployment and after all, a risk you don't need if you can "go with the tide" until you land a better job.

You have your own manager playing against you (that's why I'm against telling people how to do their job if they are not under my management, you never know how they'll react), this is a more than good reason to leave his/her team and move on with your career; the best option you have here is to take it easy and focus on the next step and until that comes, hold on and save you the stress of landing another job quick. In brief: don't change one source of stress for another.